# Can I put 2 or 3 or event more sentence in reference text that will be used to generate the language model

Tags: cmusphinx

I have read some [tutorial on creating lm](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm#arpa_model_training). I was a little confuse about weather.txt.
I have sentences like this: (putting  silence mark at the start and end of the sentence.)

```
  <s> OK </s>

  <s> IS THERE A COMPUTER IN MY ROOM </s>
```

can I put two sentences into 1 sentence ? (putting  silence mark at the start and end of the sentence.)

```
  <s> OK . IS THERE A COMPUTER IN MY ROOM </s>
```

we tried, seem works fine , provided with the wav file , say the 2 sentence together.

Even more , can I put all about 60~100 sentences into one , and with end punctuation spot : '.' to split each sentence ?

```
<s> OK . IS THERE A COMPUTER IN MY ROOM。YES,THERE IS ON THE DESK.  RIGHT. ARE THERE ANY BALLS  </s>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do anything, but it's better to have one line per sentence.

Dots must be removed before lm training.